# Convert C code to MIPS

Tags: c, mips

I have the following C code which needs to be translated to MIPS:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     // Two strings, 100 bytes allocated for each
     char s1[100];
     char s2[100];

     printf("Enter string 1: ");
     scanf("%s", s1);

     printf("Enter string 2: ");
     scanf("%s", s2);

     int index = 0;
     while (1)
     {
         // Load characters from s1 and s2
         char c1 = s1[index];
         char c2 = s2[index];

         // Current character is greater for s1
         if (c1 > c2)
         {
             printf("s1 > s2\n");
             break;
         }

         // Current character is greater for s2
         if (c1 < c2)
         {
             printf("s1 < s2\n");
             break;
         } 

         // End of strings reached
         if (c1 == 0)
         {
            printf("The strings are equal\n");
            break;
         }

         // Compare next character
         index++;
     }
}
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
.data  
s1: .space 100  
s2: .space 100 
enters1: .asciiz "Enter string 1: "  
enters2: .asciiz "\nEnter string 2: "  
equalprint: .asciiz "The strings are equal\n"  
s2lessthans1: .asciiz "\ns1 > s2\n"
s1lessthans2: .asciiz "\ns1 < s2\n"  

.text
.globl main

main:  
li $v0,4         
la $a0,enters1  
syscall

li $v0,8
la $a0,s1
addi $a1,$zero,20
syscall         

li $v0,4        
la $a0,enters2
syscall

li $v0,8
la $a0,s2
addi $a1,$zero,20
syscall         

la $a0,s1             
la $a1,s2                    
jal compare   

beq $v0, $0, equalprint
slt $t0, $v0, $0
bne $t0, $0, str1smallerprint
j str2smallerprint

end:
    addi $v0, $0, 10
    syscall

compare:
    add $t1, $s0, $t0
    lbu $t2, 0($t1)
    add $t1, $s1, $t0
    lbu $t3, 0($t1)
    slt $t4, $t2, $t3
    bne $t4, $0, str1smaller
    beq $t2, $0, equal
    addi $a0, $t2, 0
    li $v0, 11
    syscall
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    j compare

str1smaller:
    addi $v0, $0, -1
    jr $ra

str2smaller:
    addi $v0, $0, 1
    jr $ra

equal:
    addi $v0, $0, 0
    jr $ra

equalstrings:
    la $a0, equalprint
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    j end

str1smallerprint:
    la $a0, s1lessthans2
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    j end

str2smallerprint:
    la $a0, s2lessthans1
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    j end
```

When I assemble and run on MARS MIPS, it says assembled successfully, but line 16

```
lbu $t2, 0($t1)
```

has the error:

```
Error in line 47: Runtime exception at 0x00400078: address out of range 0x00000000
```

I'm not sure where I went wrong or what to fix to get rid of this error, any help?

EDIT: FIXED CODE

```
.data 
s1: .space 100 
s2: .space 100 
enters1: .asciiz "Enter string 1: " 
enters2: .asciiz "\nEnter string 2: " 
equalprint: .asciiz "The strings are equal\n" 
s2lessthans1: .asciiz "\ns1 > s2\n"
s1lessthans2: .asciiz "\ns1 < s2\n"

.text
.globl main

main: 
li $v0, 4 
la $a0, enters1 
syscall

li $v0, 8
la $a0, s1
addi $a1, $0, 100
syscall

li $v0, 4 
la $a0, enters2
syscall

li $v0, 8
la $a0, s2
addi $a1, $0, 100
syscall

loop:
    lb $t1,s1($t0)
    lb $t2,s2($t0)
    blt $t1,$t2,s2lts1
    bgt $t1,$t2,s1lts2
    beq $t1,$0,s1eqs2
    addi $t0,$t0,1
    j loop

s1lts2:
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, s1lessthans2
    syscall
    j end

s2lts1:
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, s2lessthans1
    syscall
    j end

s1eqs2:
    li $v0, 4 
    la $a0, equalprint
    syscall

end:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Use a cross-compiler, e.g. a suitably configured [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trace through the code, at the moment you hit that `lbu`, neither `t0` nor `s0` have been initialized, and if MARS initializes your registers to 0, then yeah, your `t1` will end up a NULL pointer.

Comment: I edited the code, now I have a runtime exception at line 47 which is 'lbu $t2, 0($t1)'

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger? Incidentally, you can't have two `jal`s in a row like you do. I'm not sure why you have them there to begin with, but `jal` has a delay slot that should contain a non-delay-slot instruction.

Comment: that was a mistake in copying the code. I tried stepping through the code, but I'm not familiar with MARS so I'm not sure what it's telling me as I step through

Comment: You now have a `beq` in the delay slot of your `jal`.. also not allowed. ;) I'm updating my answer based on your edited post, but if you used a debugger, the answer should be obvious.

Comment: since you said jal has a delay slot, do I need to change jal compare to j compare? or do I need to take out the beq? I'm very new to MIPS and I'm not sure of all the syntax rules

Comment: `beq` is itself an instruction that has a delay slot, so you cannot put it into the delay slot of another instruction. If you have nothing useful to do in the delay slot, put in a `nop`. If you split up the `la` mnemonic into its separate `lui` and `ori` instructions, you could put the `ori` into the delay slot.

Comment: I'm still confused what I need to change? The first beq or the second (in the compare block)? The compiler says the error is with lbu $t2, 0($t1)

Comment: The compiler says there is an error? Or the runtime? If the runtime, I already posted an answer that tells you what the problem is (uninitialized registers). As far as instructions with delay slots, just put in a non-delay-slot instruction (but with the understand that the instruction always gets executed before the branch is taken) or a `nop` is there's nothing useful you can put in there.

Comment: And, yeah, I notice a bunch of places where you have either have bad instructions or wrong instructions in the delay slots. I'm surprised MARS doesn't complain, but it's not well-formed MIPS code.. perhaps the simulator doesn't care, but it would be a problem on an actual RISC chip.

Comment: could you edit your answer to explain which parts are wrong/need to be fixed?

Comment: My answer simply states why you are hitting the NULL pointer that MARS is reporting. It's up to you how `t0` and `s0` are supposed to be initialized. This sounds homework-y.

Comment: Note that MARS (and SPIM) doesn't simulate branch delay slots by default. It exists as a feature, but has to be explicitly enabled.

Comment: Ahh, ok, that's weird that it doesn't simulate that.. I'm too used to the real thing (from PlayStation1) and so these things pop out at me like nails scratching a chalkboard. :)

Comment: Since this is your code, what was *your* intention for what the registers `t0` and `s0` should be holding? You just need initialize those registers with whatever you intended them to hold. Have you looked at the code again now that I've told you that those registers are uninitialized?

Comment: yes, s0 should be holding the first string and t0 should be zero I believe, but I still get the same error

Comment: You need to post updated code then. The same error implies you are still getting a NULL pointer, and if you properly initialized those registers, you shouldn't have a NULL pointer.